# Vuex getter in component not updating

Tags: vue.js, store, vuex, getter

[store.state image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5X11c.png)

Here is getter from component computed:

```
        computed: {
        get_indicatorsSubMenuButtons(){

            let p = this.$store.getters.get_indicatorsMainMenuButtonActive[0].mainMenuButtonJson;
            let j;
            switch(p) {
                case 'getFuelStock':
                    j = this.$store.getters.get_indicatorsSubMenuButtons[0].indicatorSubFilters;
                    break;
                case 'getFuelSell':
                    j = this.$store.getters.get_indicatorsSubMenuButtons[1].indicatorSubFilters;
                    break;
                case 'getArticleSell':
                    j = this.$store.getters.get_indicatorsSubMenuButtons[2].indicatorSubFilters;
                    break;
            }
            return j;
        },
    },
```

and here is getter from vuex:

```
        get_indicatorsSubMenuButtons: (state) => {
            let activeMainMenuButton = state.indicatorsMainMenuButtons.filter(item => item.active === true)[0].mainMenuButtonJson;
            let r  = state.indicatorsSubMenuButtons;
            return r;
        },
```

When i change active state of each button, all data in store are updating, and getter too. But this getter in component update only when component mounts, and when i change states of parent menu.

mutation in vuex:

```
        TOGGLE_MARKING_SETTINGS_SUB_MENU_ITEM: (state, payload) => {
            console.log('payload',payload);
            let o = payload.subFilterId,
                n = payload.subFilterName,
                s = payload.active;

            let activeMainType = state.indicatorsMainMenuButtons.filter(item => item.active === true)[0].mainMenuButtonJson;

            //Vue.set(vm.items, indexOfItem, newValue)

            let v = state.indicatorsSubMenuButtons;
            let vf = v.filter(item => item.subTypeName == activeMainType)[0];

            for (var i = 0; i < vf.indicatorSubFilters.length; i++) {



                if(vf.indicatorSubFilters[i].subFilterId == o){

                    Vue.set(
                        vf.indicatorSubFilters[i], 
                        'active', 
                        true
                    );

                } else {

                    Vue.set(
                        vf.indicatorSubFilters[i], 
                        'active', 
                        false
                    );

                };



            };

        },
```

store init:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        indicatorsSubMenuButtons: [

        ],
```

Comment: How are you setting it? there are some common traps that can make settings values fail

Comment: @Ferrybig, added mutation in quastion. I mutate state.indicatorsSubMenuButtons.filter(item => item.subTypeName == activeMainType)[0].indicatorSubFilters[i]  where subFilterId ==state.indicatorsMainMenuButtons.filter(item => item.active === true)[0].mainMenuButtonJson

Comment: Is the store values defined? Give example of your store state initialization.

Comment: @Jeremy Walters, look) i've made same store state, action, mutation and getter for parent menu buttons, where state property consists of ARRAY -> OBJECT -> .active: false. And it works. But here ARRAY -> OBJECT -> ARRAY -> active:false

Comment: @ERomulon, I cant find the problem. If you dont get it right, make a code template somthing like this https://codesandbox.io/s/535kx57jpx. Then I would be able to debug it better.